# u'Georges Méliès' vs u'Georges M\xe9li\xe8s'

Tags: python, unicode

I've read a dozen pages but im still not getting it.
Where is the difference between these versions:

`u'Georges Méliès'` and `u'Georges M\xe9li\xe8s'`

and how do convert one to the other and vice-versa?

Comment: hehe .. not yet .. but im playing with the movie info and am trying to save it as a dict like im getting in from tmdb :)

Comment: hmmm .. i just found out that the DictionaryField which i used was broken and didn't allow me to save otherwise totally correct unicode data :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same, and I would add:

`u'Georges Méliès'.encode('latin1')` gives `'Georges M\xe9li\xe8s'`

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference after those strings have been parsed by the interpreter.

One version simply puts the special characters, but it requires the source file to have a special encoding, such as UTF-8.
The second version replaces those characters with their byte representation, so it's safe to have such strings in an ASCII-encoded file.

You can't talk about "converting" between them, because they are essentially the same strings. But here is something that may be interesting.

`print u'Georges M\xe9li\xe8s'` gives the output `Georges Méliès` and
`print repr(u'Georges Méliès')` gives `u'Georges M\xe9li\xe8s'`

Comment: You should never make people read escaped Unicode text. It is completely obfuscatory and backwards.  Just use UTF-8 directly, and specify the encoding. Anything else is a mess.

Comment: It should be worth noting that as of Python 3.x the `repr` form no longer defaults to explicit showing the escaped chars - it is identical to the `str` output.

Comment: In Python 3 there is the `ascii` function that does the escaping.